# print all 5 lines underneath a specific string in all files with name in subdirectories

Tags: linux, grep, find

I have a dir that contains many sub dir which all has a file 'name' I want to print in each file 'name' 5 lines under each string 'str'

Comment: Can you rewrite question as it is unclear what you are asking: “Somehow it seems to fill my head with ideas — only I don't exactly know what they are!”

Answer (score 0):

This prints the 5 following lines after a line with 'str' was found. (Hope this is what you want):

```
find . -type f -name name | xargs awk '/^str$/ {i=1; next;} \
                                           i>0 {print; if(i<5) i++; else i=0;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

**With grep**

```
find -type f -name "name" -exec grep -F -h "str" -A5 {} +
```

This finds all files named "name" and, for each file, executes a grep for string "str". The `-A5` flag asks `grep` to display the 5 lines that follow each match. `-h` keeps `grep` from displaying the filename.

**With sed**

```
find -type f -name "name" -exec sed -n -s '/txt/,+5 p' {} +
```

Same here. `sed -n` doesn't print lines. Lines are only output if they are inside a `/txt/,+5` block, meaning "6 lines starting from line containing 'txt'" (including it).

**Without the matching line**

Both solutions print the line containing "txt". If you don't want it, use `sed` to delete it:

```
find -type f -name "name" -exec sed -n -s '/txt/,+5 { /txt/ d; p }' {} +
```

Comment: @OferSabo You're welcome. Now, as the question poster, it would be kind of you to vote for the answers that you find interesting (mine and/or FloHe's, or none of them); and to choose (or not...) the one that best answers your question.